# Django: IndexError at /admin/auth/user/ list index out of range

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have 2 models: customers(which contain user = m.ForeignKey(User, related_name="customers")) and UserAdmin (class UserAdmin(NestedModelAdmin, DjangoUserAdmin)). I want add to users field, which generate link to orders for every user: in app/models.py i wrote this code:

```
def orders_url(self):
return format_html(u"<a href='/admin/order/order/?q={0}'>Orders</a>", self.user.first_name)
```

And in app/admin/user_admin.py i have this code:

```
from myproject.customer.models import Customer
def orders_url(self, user):
    customer = user.customers.all()[0]
    return customer.orders_url()
```

When I trying to search some user(for example /admin/auth/user/?q=Nick), all goes good,and it generate link to Nick's orders, but when I go in /admin/auth/user/, i see this error: IndexError at /admin/auth/user/
list index out of range. 
Traceback link to next code:

```
path_to_project/customer/admin/user_admin.py in orders_url
                customer = user.customers.all()[0] 
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
self       <myproject.customer.admin.user_admin.UserAdmin object at 0xa7e788c>
user       <User: >
```

Forgot about that message:

```
Error during template rendering
In template /home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 91
list index out of range
91 {% result_list cl %}
```

How can I change it?

Comment: The user object you're working with doesn't have any customers

Comment: i see that even user is empty, but i don't know which this user and where i can add user to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing last line in user_admin.py file orders_url method:

```
def orders_url(self, user):
    customers = user.customers.all()
    return format_html(', '.join([customer.orders_url() for customer in customers]))
```

Now all stuff works fine.